# Modificar estilos de los option de un select

Tags: html, jquery, css

Tengo un select pero quiero personalizarlo completamente. Quiero que sea como la primera foto, pero me sale como la segunda y no soy capaz de encontrar la manera de editar los options.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi código:

```css
select {
  font-family: Rubik;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
  appearance: none;
  outline-width: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline;
  width: 10em;
  border: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: 1.29;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  color: #3a3a3a;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-bottom: 0px solid #757575;
  option {
    padding: 20px;
    display: inline;
    width: 10em;
    border: none;
    color: #3a3a3a;
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="mounth">
  <option value="hide">FILTER</option>
  <option value="january" rel="icon-temperature">January</option>
  <option value="february">February</option>
  <option value="march">March</option>
  <option value="april">April</option>
</select>
```

Lo que quisiera conseguir es el padding, que el hover sea de ese color y cambiar el color del borde del cuadro de los select.

Comment: ¿Estás usando css puro o también tienes Bootstrap? Si es tu caso usar bootstrap, hay varias formas.

Answer (score 0):

No se puede. Tal cual.

Cuando veas un formulario espectacular, revisa bien que utiliza tags nativos. Generalmente, los super formularios visuales son ilusiones: bloques de código llenos de `eventListener` y que inyectan las "respuestas reales" en formularios escondidos.

Por ejemplo, este código te permite decir qué número te gusta,  pinchando sobre el botón. Cuando aprietas encima, una función envía el valor real al input real, pero el usuario solo clickea botones.

```js
function meGusta(option) {
  // aquí inserto el valor enviado por el botón en el input oculto
  document.querySelector('input[name=selectValue]').value = option;
}
```

```html
<!-- un input oculto que almacena la información -->
<input type="hidden" name="selectValue">

<!-- posibles opciones -->
<button onclick="meGusta(1)">Quiero el 1</button>
<button onclick="meGusta(2)">Quiero el 2</button>
<button onclick="meGusta(3)">Quiero el 3</button>
```

Para no extenderme mucho, por favor, visita esta documentación donde está super bien explicado:

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_custom_select

Comment: Al final vi que era casi imposible y repliqué el select con un dropdown.